# Does Kubernetes wait for readiness probe to pass to add the POD entry in DNS

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Does Kubernetes wait for readiness probe to pass to add the POD entry in DNS?
I have observed that POD hostname do not have any entry in DNS if readiness probe is still running after the POD start.
Once the readiness probe pass, entry is created in the DNS.

My openshift version is 3.11 which has kubernetes version 1.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's true, it's `readinessprobe` designed to.

When readiness probe is not passed, the pod will be in `NotReady` status, thus doesn't appear in the Endpoint list, while only the Pods in the Endpoint list will be resolved by coredns.  This can effectively prevent the end user from accessing the newly started Pod when Pod's service not ready yet.

Comment: As a warning: "DNS resolution is never real-time"